# ServiceStack Route design

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

Are these 3 routes the same? Which one is normally preferred?

```
[Route("/todo/{id}", "DELETE")]
[Route("/todo/delete","POST")]
[Route("/todo/delete/{id}","GET")]
public class DeleteTodo : IReturnVoid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred route is actually to include the `Id` in the pathinfo since **DELETE** requests don't have a HTTP Request Body you can submit this info on, e.g:

```
[Route("/todo/{id}", "DELETE")]
public class DeleteTodo : IReturnVoid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

For pragmatic reasons you may want to allow a **POST** to do the DELETE since browsers my default (and some proxies) don't allow sending of DELETE Requests.

```
[Route("/todo/{id}/delete", "POST")]
public class DeleteTodo : IReturnVoid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You can simulate a **DELETE** request in Ajax or jQuery by adding the **X-Http-Method-Override** HTTP Request header in your Ajax call or as a field in your FormData or QueryString, e.g.

```
POST /todo/1
X-Http-Method-Override=DELETE
```

or embedded in the HTML FormData like:

```
<form action="/todo/1" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="X-Http-Method-Override" value="DELETE"/>
</form>
```

Though it's important not to allow DELETE's via GET as by contract GET's should have no side-effects so are safe to be cached and replayed by HTTP middle-ware like proxies, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to follow REST guidelines, you should not use GET or POST to delete a resource.

> The GET verb is used to read a resource.  An important rule of thumb
>   is that a GET operation is safe.  That is, it can be done repeatedly
>   without changing visibly the state of the resource.  This property is
>   very important for various reasons.  First, indexing engines use GET
>   to index the contents of a resource.  So it would be bad if indexing a
>   resource also changed it.  Second, intermediaries, such as proxies,
>   may cache results of a GET operation to accelerate subsequent accesses
>   to the same resource.
>
> The PUT and DELETE verbs allow a request to alter the state of a
>   resource atomically.
>
> The POST verb can carry a variety of meanings.  It's the Swiss Army
>   Knife of HTTP verbs.  For some resources, it may be used to alter the
>   internal state.  For others, its behavior may be that of a remote
>   procedure call.

Have a look at that [page](http://developer.mindtouch.com/REST/REST_for_the_Rest_of_Us) for a complete description.