# How to implement Delete service call using ServiceStack

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I have couple of questions related to REST service implementation using ServiceStack.

1. For GET operation, I define my request DTO as below :

   ```
   [Route("/Customer/{ID}", Verbs = "GET")]
   public class GetCustomer : IReturn<GetCustomerResponse>
   {
       ....
       ....
   }
   ```

Here "GetCustomer" is request DTO and "GetCustomerResponse" is response DTO. But for PUT/POST/DELETE operation, I just need to know whether operation got committed successfully or not and if 'not' then what is the exception. So what should be my request dto definition for POST/PUT/DELETE? Should it use IReturnVoid as shown below?

```
[Route("/Customer/{ID}", Verbs = "DELETE")]
public class DeleteCustomer : IReturnVoid
{
    ....
    ....
}
```

If I have to use IReturnVoid then how I can retrieve any exception information that might occur on committing my operation?

In the error handling document for service stack it is written and I quote below

> Error Response Types
>
> The Error Response that gets returned when an Exception is thrown
>   varies on whether a conventionally-named {RequestDto}Response DTO
>   exists or not.
>
> If it exists:
>
> The {RequestDto}Response is returned, regardless of the service
>   method's response type. If the {RequestDto}Response DTO has a
>   ResponseStatus property, it is populated otherwise no ResponseStatus
>   will be returned. (If you have decorated the {ResponseDto}Response
>   class and properties with [DataContract]/[DataMember] attributes, then
>   ResponseStatus also needs to be decorated, to get populated).
>
> Otherwise, if it doesn't:
>
> A generic ErrorResponse gets returned with a populated ResponseStatus
>   property.
>
> The Service Clients transparently handles the different Error Response
>   types, and for schema-less formats like JSON/JSV/etc there's no actual
>   visible difference between returning a ResponseStatus in a custom or
>   generic ErrorResponse - as they both output the same response on the
>   wire.

What I'm not getting from above is what should be the return type for my Delete method in my service implementation? How I can implement my delete method without defining delete response DTO but yet I'm able to retrieve 'ErrorResponse' n exception info?

2. Is it possible to define route with "DELETE" verb? I have following implementation.

**Route:**

```
[Route("/DeleteCustomer/{ID}", Verbs = "DELETE")]
public class DeleteCustomer : IReturn<DeleteCustomerResponse>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

**Method implementation:**

```
public DeleteContactResponse Delete(DeleteContact request)
{
    .....
}
```

But whenever I call this delete using my client, I always get "NotFound" exception. I tried different clients but with all I get 404 error.

One of the [reference link](http://blogs.askcts.com/2014/05/15/getting-started-with-servicestack-part-3/) available alongwith Servicestack document reuses the "GET" and "DELETE" verb together.

Another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711522/servicestack-route-design) suggests not all browsers support delete operation.

So I wonder how Delete operation should be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fix for my 2nd question from following two links :
1. [Link1](https://codesupport.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/404/)
2. [Link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1961593.aspx?DELETE%20PUT%20verbs%20result%20in%20404%20Not%20Found%20in%20WebAPI%20only%20when%20running%20locally)

I don't fully understand this fix but doing above changes worked for me and now I can call Delete function from any clients.

For 1st question, pls refer @mythz 's reply below in detail.

Answer (score 15):

See this earlier answer for details on how to design a [REST-ful API with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785).

The [CustomerRestExample](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/CustomerRestExample.cs) contains a complete stand-alone example of a Customer REST ServiceStack Service:

### Customer Service Definition

Here's an example of the custom Routes and Request DTO's of what a typical Customer REST Service could look like:

```
[Route("/customers", "GET")]
public class GetCustomers : IReturn<GetCustomersResponse> {}

public class GetCustomersResponse
{
    public List<Customer> Results { get; set; } 
}

[Route("/customers/{Id}", "GET")]
public class GetCustomer : IReturn<Customer>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Route("/customers", "POST")]
public class CreateCustomer : IReturn<Customer>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("/customers/{Id}", "PUT")]
public class UpdateCustomer : IReturn<Customer>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("/customers/{Id}", "DELETE")]
public class DeleteCustomer : IReturnVoid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

OrmLite POCO Model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially the Custom Routes identify the Resource whilst the HTTP VERB indicates the operation on that Resource. Looking at the HTTP Requests makes this a little clearer:

```
GET    /customers   -> return all Customers
POST   /customers   -> Create a new Customer
GET    /customers/1 -> return Customer 1
PUT    /customers/1 -> Update Customer 1
DELETE /customers/1 -> Delete Customer 1
```

### Customer Service Implementation

With the above DTO's definitions in-place, we can now implement this Customer REST Service by adding an implementation for each Request DTO - in this example using [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite):

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
    public object Get(GetCustomers request)
    {
        return new GetCustomersResponse { Results = Db.Select<Customer>() };
    }

    public object Get(GetCustomer request)
    {
        return Db.SingleById<Customer>(request.Id);
    }

    public object Post(CreateCustomer request)
    {
        var customer = new Customer { Name = request.Name };
        Db.Save(customer);
        return customer;
    }

    public object Put(UpdateCustomer request)
    {
        var customer = Db.SingleById<Customer>(request.Id);
        if (customer == null)
            throw HttpError.NotFound("Customer '{0}' does not exist".Fmt(request.Id));

        customer.Name = request.Name;
        Db.Update(customer);

        return customer;
    }

    public void Delete(DeleteCustomer request)
    {
        Db.DeleteById<Customer>(request.Id);
    }
}
```

### Customer Usage Example

With the above Customer REST Service implementation, we can re-use the Request DTO's with ServiceStack's [.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) to provide an end-to-end Typed API without code-gen, i.e:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);

//GET /customers
var all = client.Get(new GetCustomers());                         // Count = 0

//POST /customers
var customer = client.Post(new CreateCustomer { Name = "Foo" });

//GET /customer/1
customer = client.Get(new GetCustomer { Id = customer.Id });      // Name = Foo

//GET /customers
all = client.Get(new GetCustomers());                             // Count = 1

//PUT /customers/1
customer = client.Put(
    new UpdateCustomer { Id = customer.Id, Name = "Bar" });       // Name = Bar

//DELETE /customers/1
client.Delete(new DeleteCustomer { Id = customer.Id });

//GET /customers
all = client.Get(new GetCustomers());                             // Count = 0
```

The comments above include the HTTP Operations performed in each Service Client example.

Comment: what if the Delete fails?  can something be returned to indicate Success/Fail?