# ServiceStack batabase first OrmLite.Poco.cs generated, now what?

Tags: servicestack, poco, ormlite-servicestack

there are extremely few docs about ServiceStack around. Let alone database first approach. So now I have `OrmLite.Poco.cs` with all the models mapped from SQL Server. What is the next step? Add routes to the models on `OrmLite.Poco.cs` or copy out each class into individual `.cs` file then add routes to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great you now have your Table POCO's which you can start querying with, e.g:

```
var results = Db.Select<Poco>();
```

Custom Routes only go on **Request DTO's** you should not re-use your OrmLite models to also define the contract for your Services.

For an example, checkout this Simple OrmLite Database sample showing how to use the `Customer` Table POCO in OrmLite to create a [Simple Customer REST Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273466/85785).

Comment: I printed out the `Simple Customer REST Service` answer @mythz referred to above and use it religiously.  Conceivably the only improvement would be to include `[DTO class] : IReturn<[resource]>` to most DTOs, to have a more strongly typed response to the various actions.