# Naming service methods in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, routes, servicestack

I am creating my first ServiceStack application.  I think it is great but find that I have limited flexibility in the naming of methods in the Services.  An example of this is I wanted to name this method GetChannels(AllChannels) but the route was not created as seen in the metadata page.  I found it did work if I named it

```
        public object Get(AllChannels request)
```

Do these methods have to be named by the Verb that will call it?  I am doing my routing in AppHost in the Configure().

Am I missing something?  Is there a way for the route to specify the method to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use either the Verb that you want to limit your Service to be called from or `Any()` which allows it to be called from ANY HTTP verb. Your Operation name in ServiceStack should instead be on the Request DTO, so I would change your Request DTO to be:

```
public object Get(GetAllChannels request)
```

ServiceStack promotes a message-based design where your Request DTO defines your Service contract not your methods. Please read these existing answers for learning how to design message-based Services with ServiceStack:

- [Designing a REST-ful service with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822)
- [Simple Customer REST Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273466)
- [How to design a Message-Based API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229)