# Can I use ServiceStack routes with method parameters instead of a DTO class for every request?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I love the capability of ASP.NET MVC controllers, in terms of being able to add a route attribute that maps a certain part of the URL to a method parameter, i.e.:

```
[Route("there/are/{howManyDucks}/swimming/in/the/{bodyOfWaterType}")]
public string NotifyDucksSwimming(int howManyDucks, string bodyOfWaterType)
{
 ...
}
```

Is there an equivalent way of doing this with ServiceStack and skip making a DTO class for each type of request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a fundamental concept in [ServiceStack's message-based design](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services) that all Services accept a Request DTO which is what's used to [define your Service Contract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369736/85785). Nearly all of ServiceStack's surrounding feature ecosystem is possible because your Service Contract is defined in a separate [clean, impl and dependency-free DTO's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937634/servicestack-architecture-reusing-pocos-for-everything/32940275#32940275) which is contra to the [RPC Services Design WCF, MVC and Web API encourage](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack) where your Service Contract is coupled to your Server method implementations.

The Equivalent in ServiceStack would be:

```
//Request DTO

[Route("/there/are/{HowManyDucks}/swimming/in/the/{BodyOfWaterType}")]
public class NotifyDucksSwimming 
{
    public int HowManyDucks { get; set; }
    public string BodyOfWaterType { get; set; }
}

//Implementation

public object Any(NotifyDucksSwimming request)
{
    //...
}
```

However stuffing all properties in the `/path/info` is not great API design, so I'd recommend looking at these answers below for some API design examples:

- [Designing a REST-ful service with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785)
- [Simple Customer REST Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273466/85785)

So I'd opt for a API endpoint that represents a resource, potentially:

```
[Route("/ducks/{BodyOfWaterType}")]
public class NotifyDucksSwimming 
{
    public int HowManyDucks { get; set; }
    public string BodyOfWaterType { get; set; }
}
```

In ServiceStack you only need to specify the `/path/{info}` as all other parameters can automatically be populated by any other means, e.g: QueryString, FormData, Serialized Body, HTTP Param Header Overrides, etc.

So the Custom route above will allow you to call the Service with:

- /ducks/lake?HowManyDucks=10

#### No Ceremony Razor Views

Also if this API is only for executing within a Razor page in most cases you don't need a Service at all as ServiceStack lets you [call the Razor Pages directly with its No Ceremony Pages feature](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts#the-no-ceremony-option---dynamic-pages-without-controllers).

Comment: Thanks for confirming!